# Why my docker image does not want to deploy on azure web services?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service

i have an issue with deploying Docker container to Azure Web Services, it is showing only for this whole time:
[Azure view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4kyO.png)

Do you have maybe an idea why is it like that? This is my docker file:
[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5zlw.png)

And im doing those steps: first programming, then pulling to github, then using Docker Image:Build Image, and then using command:

```
docker pull xxxx/xxxx:latest
```

And waiting for result, but it is not changing anything, i have the basic plan, so i cannot use better plan, im using Docker Hub service
[Azure view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy2ah.png)
And these are the settings

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but have you tried

```bash
docker push xxxx/xxxx:latest
```

this will upload your docker image to the registry so that azure can then download your image.

Comment: Yes, i did, unfortunately it still doesn't work